# how to display particular div when particular radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build something similar to this, http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection-in-jquery.php, with the difference that after selecting the radio button, I also need to press a submit button in order to display the div that goes with that particular button.    Also how do I swap the div displayed, should the client change their mind?

JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nag0vdut/

**HTML**

```
<div class="steps">
    <h2>2. Valj din bankskivas</h2>
    <div id="step2">
        <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan" style="background-image:url(media/images/plan1.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan1" name="plan"/></div><p>Enkel bankskiva</p></span>
        <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan2.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan2" name="plan"/></div><p>L-form</p></span>
        <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan3.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan3" name="plan"/></div><p>U-form</p></span>
        <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan4.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan4" name="plan"/></div><p>Mattbestallning</p></span>
        <button type="button" class="nasta" onClick="processStep2()">Nasta</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="steps">
    <h2>3.  Närmare information</h2>
    <div id="step3">
        <div class="step_left">
            <div class="plan1">
                <h3>3.1. Välj bänkskivans mått (mm)*</h3>
                <div class="shape" id="plan1_shape">
                    <h2>
                        Plan 1
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="shape" id="plan2_shape">
                    <h2>
                        plan 2
                    </h2>

                </div>  
                <div class="shape" id="plan3_shape">
                    <h2>
                        Plan 3
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <div class="shape" id="plan4_shape">
                    <h2>
                        Plan 4
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="step3_p2">
                    <h3>3.2. Välj bänkskivans kantbehandling</h3>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="measures_show"/>Välj kantprofil samt bearbetnig av synliga kanter från ritningen ovan.</p>
                        <div class="plan_select">
                            <h3>Tiles - Selected</h3>
                            <?php bank_select("SELECT * FROM bankskivans WHERE typeID = 0"); ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var tile, plan;

function _(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function processStep2() {
    plan = _("plan").value;
    if ($(".radio").is(":checked")) {
        _("step2").style.display = "none";
        _("step3").style.display = "block";
        /* section I am having issues with */
        if ($(".radio").value.is(":checked") == "plan1") {

            $("#plan1_shape").style.display = "block";

        } else {
            alert("wrong window");
        }
        $("#phase2").removeClass("phase");
        $("#phase3").removeClass("main_list");
        $("#phase2").addClass("main_list");
        $("#phase3").addClass("phase");
    } else {
        alert("chose radio button")

    }
}
```

Comment: you linked blank jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for telling me.

Comment: @ChriChri We need you to post your html as well, it's much easier to understand and see what needs to happen if we can actually link id's and class names to concrete dom elements.
Probably relevant css as well as you're adding and removing classes

Comment: may b correction is 1)do `$('input[name=plan]:checked').val()` instead of `$(".radio").value.is(":checked")` and do `$("#plan1_shape")[0].style...`

Comment: @ChriChri I didnt see your jsfiddle until now, my bad OP. So could you verify that what you WANT is to happen something different when the user selects the first radiobutton and clicks the submit button?

Comment: Something different when each radio button is selected, not just the first one.  ie radio button 1 - display "plan_shape1", radio button 2 - display "plan shape2", ect.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using radiobuttons, there can only exist one radiobutton that is checked.

```
function process_step2(){

    divName = $(":checked").val(); //get the name of the phase you want to show
    $(".phases").hide();    //hide all phases initially
    $("#"+divName).show();  //only show the phase that you want to show
});
```

So you need to give every phase a classname like `class = "phases"` if you follow my example. Then hide them all, and then only show the one you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Try, in processStep2()

```
if ($('input[name=plan]:checked').val()) {
  $('#' + $('input[name=plan]:checked').val() + "_shape")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

As you say..on plan1 click plan1_shape will be display plan2 click plan2_shape will be display etc..

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/nag0vdut/3/)

Comment: If i decide to swap, how do I hide the first div displayed?

Comment: @ChriChri try `$('div[class="shape"]').hide();` in if tag..let me know if its not working